# What should i do exactly when i get errors with choises when building jhbuild

Tags: gtk3, jhbuild

Im trying to install `Gtk+3`. During the installation of `jhbuild` i got cleared with `jhbuild sanitycheck`, `jhbuild sysdeps --install`. As the next step i did `jhbuild build`, now i get errors with multiple choises

one such error is:

```
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> dconf -> glib -> gvfs -> glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> dconf -> glib -> glib-networking -> glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> dconf -> glib -> dconf
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> evolution-data-server -> gtk+ -> adwaita-icon-theme -> gtk+
W: gnome-control-center has a dependency on unknown "network-manager-applet" module
W: gnome-control-center has a dependency on unknown "network-manager-applet" module
W: mutter has a dependency on unknown "libXi" module
W: mutter has a dependency on unknown "xwayland" module
W: grilo-plugins has a dependency on unknown "libdmapsharing" module
W: meta-gnome-apps-tested has a dependency on unknown "aisleriot" module
W: gnome-initial-setup has a dependency on unknown "network-manager-applet" module
W: gnome-software has a dependency on unknown "fwupd" module
W: rygel has a dependency on unknown "valadoc" module
*** Checking out itstool *** [1/225]
*** Skipping itstool (package and dependencies not updated) *** [1/225]
*** Checking out yelp-xsl *** [2/225]
*** Skipping yelp-xsl (package and dependencies not updated) *** [2/225]
*** Checking out yelp-tools *** [3/225]
*** Skipping yelp-tools (package and dependencies not updated) *** [3/225]
*** Checking out gtk-doc *** [4/225]
*** Skipping gtk-doc (package and dependencies not updated) *** [4/225]
*** Checking out glib *** [5/225]
*** Skipping glib (package and dependencies not updated) *** [5/225]
*** Checking out vala *** [6/225]
*** Skipping vala (package and dependencies not updated) *** [6/225]
*** Checking out dconf *** [7/225]
*** Configuring dconf *** [7/225]
./configure --prefix /home/username/releases/gnome-apps-3.17.3/install  --disable-static --disable-gtk-doc --disable-Werror 
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-static, --disable-Werror
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /home/username/.local/bin/install-check
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for dlsym in -lc... no
checking for dlsym in -ldl... yes
checking for valac... /home/username/releases/gnome-apps-3.17.3/install/bin/valac
checking whether /home/username/releases/gnome-apps-3.17.3/install/bin/valac is at least version 0.18.0... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for xsltproc... /usr/bin/xsltproc
checking for glib-compile-resources... /home/username/releases/gnome-apps-3.17.3/install/bin/glib-compile-resources
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
checking for gtk-doc... yes
checking for gtkdoc-check... gtkdoc-check.test
checking for gtkdoc-check... /home/username/releases/gnome-apps-3.17.3/install/bin/gtkdoc-check
checking for gtkdoc-rebase... /home/username/releases/gnome-apps-3.17.3/install/bin/gtkdoc-rebase
checking for gtkdoc-mkpdf... /home/username/releases/gnome-apps-3.17.3/install/bin/gtkdoc-mkpdf
checking whether to build gtk-doc documentation... no
checking for GTKDOC_DEPS... yes
checking for glib... yes
checking for gio... yes
checking for dbus... no
configure: error: Package requirements (dbus-1) were not met:

No package 'dbus-1' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables dbus_CFLAGS
and dbus_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
*** Error during phase configure of dconf: ########## Error running ./configure --prefix /home/username/releases/gnome-apps-3.17.3/install  --disable-static --disable-gtk-doc --disable-Werror  *** [7/225]

  [1] Rerun phase configure
  [2] Ignore error and continue to build
  [3] Give up on module
  [4] Start shell
  [5] Reload configuration
  [6] Go to phase "wipe directory and start over"
  [7] Go to phase "clean"
  [8] Go to phase "distclean"
choice:
```

what should i do exactly? (should i make changes manually on the file)

Because i chose `option 6`, and got stuck at the same error after rerunning it.

Comment: It must be showing what caused the error. What messages came before the choices were displayed?

Comment: @muru ,.. i have pasted the whole output that i get ,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need GNOME >= 3.15 and the development libraries of `libdbus-1`

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev
```